# How to get base64 of photos:// path images?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs, react-native-image

In my project I am retrieving gallery's albums using [react-native-photos-framework](https://github.com/olofd/react-native-photos-framework) which giving me gallery's album. Then using those album object I am fetching images of that particular album, which returning assets array. Those assets contains `uri` which look like this :

> "photos://C5E8291B-09C6-2231-856D-989D929392FA2/L0/001"

How I can get the base64 string of that image.

I tried to get using [react-native-image-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-base64) and [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) but none of working.

Here is a code in which I used `react-native-image-base64` :

```js
const base64 = await ImgToBase64.getBase64String("photos://C5E8291B-09C6-2231-856D-989D929392FA2/L0/001");
```

But, this giving me following error :

> JSON value '' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString

Here is code using `react-native-fs` :

```js
const base64 = await RNFS.readFile('photos://C5E8291B-09C6-2231-856D-989D929392FA2/L0/001','base64');
```

Above code giving me this error :

> "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'photos://C5E8291B-09C6-2231-856D-989D929392FA2/L0/001'"

Please help me how to solve !!!

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Another question: How do you get the `uri`?

Comment: Heyy @TimH  I edited the answer with error detail and explained how I got `uri`.